# WordPress plugins - don't print the comments on a post page

Tags: wordpress

I'm making a plugin where I want the comments in a single post page not to be printed at all. I need to query the database myself and print my own html with the results.

How can I make WordPress to not print the comments, without disabling them?

Thank you

EDIT:
as a suggestion, I am using:

```
apply_filters('comments_template', array($this,'comments_template'), 10, 1);
function comments_template($template){
    $template = '';
    return $template;
}
```

nothing happens, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `comments_template` filter to make WordPress use your plugin's template file rather than the current theme's.

EDIT: based on your edited code: unfortunately you need to have an actual file, the path to which you return in `$this->comments_template()`...

```
class MyPlugin{
      //add the filter somewhere...

      function comments_template($template){
           return dirname(__FILE__) . "/my_comments_template.php";
      }
}
```

The file `plugin_dir/my_comments_template.php` must exist, otherwise WP falls back on the default theme's `comments.php`. See wp-includes/comment-template.php on lines 911-917.

In `plugin_dir/my_comments_template.php` you could call `MyPlugin::do_comments() or something like that.  I don't know any other way around this. Let me know if you find a better way.

Cheers, Chris

Comment: thanks, but it still doesn't work... I do: apply_filters('comments_template', array($this,'comments_template'), 10, 1); on the constructor of my class, and my function isn't even called...

Comment: apply_filters or add_filter?  should be add_filter.